# How can I Redirect to the same path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I use `<Redirect to="<same_path>" />` I get a warning: `Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "<path>"`.

In my Component I open an other Component thats asking for a submit or cancel.

When the users presses submit an action will be launched and after the action the users has to be redirected to the same Component. So actually, the Component, where the user has to answer the question, will be closed and the Component where Route is at will be reloaded.

I tried `this.props.history.push(<path>);` as well.

Function what will update the state:

```
let redirectionLink = "/" + this.props.path;
this.setState({redirectTo: redirectionLink});
```

In my render:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.redirectTo !== false) {
        return <Redirect to={this.state.redirectTo} />
    }
}
```

What I expect it should do is that it just redirects to the gived path. But I get the Warning instead.

Comment: If you just want to reload the component, you don't need to redirect. Just change the values of the component that you want to reload  and it will automatically render and reload the component.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I applied this method. And it works fine now! Can you set is as Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to reload the component, you don't need to redirect. Just change the values of the component that you want to reload and it will automatically render and reload the component.

Comment: Not for me, but for people who are searching for answers... Try to add some example code :)

Comment: It is react working principle, so no need any examples. However, anybody who has questions about that issue can read the React documentation :https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html